# What sort of thing?

Tags: grammatical-number

I can't quite figure out which of the following forms is correct:

> These sorts of things are ...
>   This sort of things is ...
>   This sort of thing is ...
>   < some other option >

So, what's the right choice?

Comment: Quoting a linguist's answer to a [related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing/5546#5546), "It seems that, in phrases like 'type(s) of X' ('kind(s) of X', etc.), there is generally number concord between the type-word and the class itself. Why that is, I don't know."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the thing(s) in question, it's either

> This sort of thing is...

or

> These sorts of things are...

You need (pro)noun/verb plural agreement.

Samples:

> Yesterday I slipped on the ice.  Today I slipped on a sliver of soap.  This sort of thing is always happening to me.
>
> Last week I needed stitches from a shaving accident.  Yesterday I slipped on the ice.  Today I got hit by a car.  These sorts of things are always happening to me.

Comment: I would say *"These sort of things are..."*

Comment: @Orbling: then that would sound wrong to a lot of people. 'These sorts...' or 'This sort', not 'this sorts' or 'these sort'.

Comment: @Mitch Sentences with multiple plural parts in them usually sound wrong.

Comment: @Orbling: 'These' is plural, 'sort' is singular. I would think however wrong multiple plural words sound, to mix up plural and singular especially where it's grammatically incongruent would sound that much worse.

Comment: @Orbling, would you say "these type of chickens"?  That sounds horribly horribly wrong to me.  I would always say "These types of" for multiple types, or "This type of" for a single type.  And the same holds for other words in that position.

Comment: @Hellion: I would say *"these types of chicken"*.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these work and are idiomatically proper in English:

> ```
> These sorts of things are ...
> This sort of thing is ...
> ```

"This sort of things is ..." doesn't follow the typical idiom.
"sort of things" and "sorts of thing" are both unusual and probably better avoided.

As @Hellion's examples show, the choice of the workable phrase will be roughly determined by the number of the things in question.