# "Two types of user" or "Two types of users"?

Tags: word-usage

Which is the correct sentence to use?

> 1. Two types of **user** are identified: . . .
> 2. Two types of **users** are identified: . . .

I would have said the former (#1), but a colleague has suggested the latter (#2). The first one just sounds right to me.

Which is correct (if indeed either of them is)?

Thanks.

Comment: +1. That's an interesting question. Hopefully someone will give you a solid answer, one with vetted grammar sources to back it up. :)

Comment: Google Books is not the Bible of grammar and usage, but: [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+types+of+user%2C+two+types+of+users&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20types%20of%20user%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20types%20of%20users%3B%2Cc0) suggests that both are used, but the former is **currently** used more often. As for why, I agree with F.E.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you seek the info that's in a decent usage dictionary, such as the *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* (MWCDEU). My copy of *MWCDEU* discusses this sort of issue on pages 452-4 of the "kind" entry (it specifically mentions "type" on page 454); you should probably read the whole entry on "kind" to understand the acceptable usages. :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but there's no good answers on there. So maybe when this one's finished and got a good answer we could close that one and link it to this?

Comment: @Araucaria The data given in eric.cheung's answer sums up the situation well in my opinion. And answers here are opinionated / show lack of appreciation that the 'grammatical' / 'notional' / 'proximity' 'rules' can conflict, and that arguments based on logic and assumed derivations must defer to actual usage.

Comment: There is further readable analysis at [“Types of” followed by singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29843/types-of-followed-by-singular-or-plural). Overall, while I prefer _types of user_, I'd probably go with the majority and use _types of things_ in most cases. I think notional concord does play a part here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have a feeling that if we keep this open for a while a good answer with refs making exactly your point about usage may well appear ...

Comment: Unfortunately, that linked to thread [Types of things vs. types of thing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing) is full of guesswork and does not have much research at all, and it is full of misleading and incorrect information. It would have been nice if someone in that thread had at least accessed a decent usage dictionary, such as the *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* (MWCDEU). The *MWCDEU* has the entry "kind" on pages 452-4 where it discusses this specific issue.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this thread because that linked to thread does not have a good answer for the OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **Two types of user** are identified.
> - **Two types of users** are identified.

Both of them are correct sentence. They both can be used in formal and informal style. *kinds/sorts/types* are followed by both singular or plural nouns. I noticed that **"two types of user"** is more common in BrE, than AmE; AmE prefers **"two types of users"**.

**The following constructions are possible -**

i) These/Those kinds/types/sorts of [(singular or plural form of countable noun) or (uncountable noun)] 
ii) These/Those kind/type/sort of [(singular or plural form of countable noun) or (uncountable noun)] [INFORMAL] 
iii) All/two kinds/types/sorts of [(singular or plural form of countable noun) or (uncountable noun)] 
iv) This/That kind/type/sort of [(singular form of countable noun) or (uncountable noun)] 
v) This/That kind/type/sort of [(plural form of countable noun)] [Most people think it unacceptable, better be avoided] 
vi) This/That kind/type/sort of a singular form of countable noun [INFORMAL]

For details, see below -

---

> When it’s *this type of*, the word following is normally singular, as in
>   *this type of accident/game/garden/sausage*. The corresponding plural
>   phrase: *these types of* is much less common in both American and
>   British English, by a factor of 1:7 in CCAE and 1:10 in the BNC. *These
>   types of* takes both plural and singular nouns following, as in *these
>   types of drama* and *these types of plays*. The compromise form *these
>   type of* is rare in both databases, and mostly found in speech. Some
>   uses such as *these type of things* show it as a routine pause filler,
>   but others are deliberate: *these type of games/links/specials/
>   victim-based surveys.*
>
> <sub>**Source -** The Cambridge Guide to English Usage by Pam Peters</sub>

> **Partitive constructions -**
>
> Both count and uncountable nouns can enter partitive constructions,
>   i.e constructions denoting a part of a whole. such constructions
>   express both quality partition (*eg: a kind of paper*) and a quantity
>   partition (*eg: a piece of paper*). Quality partition is expressed by
>   a partitive count noun like *kind, sort,* or *type* followed by an
>   *of*-phrase, *eg*:
>
> > 1. a) a new kind of computer [SINGULAR PARTITIVE]
> > 2. b) new kinds of computers [PLURAL PARTITIVE]
> > 3. a) a delicious sort of bread [SINGULAR PARTITIVE]
> > 4. b) delicious sorts of bread [PLURAL PARTITIVE]
> > 5. a) another type of research [SINGULAR PARTITIVE]
> > 6. b) other types of research [PLURAL PARTITIVE]

But in informal context, the following is also acceptable -

> > These/Those sort/kind/type of parties are dangerous. [INFORMAL]
>
> <sub>**Source -** A Comprehensive Grammar of English Language by Randolph Quirk, Sidney Greenbaum, Geoffrey Leech, and Jan Svartvik (Page No. 249 and 764) [ENTRY 10.43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ijhh.jpg)</sub>

> The words *kind, sort*, and *type* can be troublesome when they are
>   used with plural nouns and modifiers. Sentences like *I hate these
>   kind of movies* may occur with some frequency but are awkward, and
>   some would say, grammatically incorrect. The Usage Panel frowns upon
>   these usages. In our 2005 survey, 81 percent rejected the use of
>   *kind* with a plural modifier and plural noun in the sentence *Those kind of buildings seem old-fashioned*. Fully 88 percent of the Panel
>   found unacceptable the use of *kind* with a singular modifier and
>   plural noun and verb in *That kind of buildings seem old fashioned*.
>   In these examples *kind* would presumably function as a determiner
>   like *number* in *A great number of people have crowded into the
>   lobby*. (Note that *number* here is singular, but the plural verb
>   *have* agrees with the plural noun *people*, so *number* is not really the subject of the sentence). This problem can be avoided by making
>   the phrase entirely singular (as in *That kind of movie is always
>   enjoyable*) or by revising so that the noun is the plural subject (as
>   in *Movies of that kind are always enjoyable*). Bear in mind that
>   plural *kinds* often implies that the phrase refers to a number of
>   different categories of things—more than one genre of movie, for
>   example. Perhaps the best solution is to drop the *kind* phrase
>   entirely (*Those movies are always enjoyable*) or to be specific
>   (*Those spy movies are always enjoyable*).
>
> <sub>**Source -** Usage Note from The American heritage Dictionary Of
>   the English Language</sub>

> *Kind, sort and type* are countable nouns.
>
> <sub>**Source -** Macmillan Dictionary</sub>

As they are countable noun, after words like **all, many, two** etc. we use **kinds**, not **kind**. We don't say *All kind of ...*, to make it correct we use *All kinds of ...*

> The article *a/an* is usually dropped after *sort of, kind of* and
>   *type of*, but structures with articles are possible in an informal style:
>
> > That's a funny **sort of (a)** car. 
> >     What **sort of (a)** bird is that?
>
> When we are talking about one sort of thing, we can use *sort of, kind
>   of* or *type of* followed by a singular noun.
>
> > This **sort of car** is enormously expensive to run. 
> >     I'm interested in any new **type of development** in computer science.
>
> Singular *sort of, kind of* and *type of* can also be followed by
>   plural nouns, especially in an informal style:
>
> > I'm interested in any new **kind of developments**.
>
> Plural demonstratives (*these* and *those*) can also be used:
>
> > **Those sort of cars** are enormously expensive to run. 
> >     Do you smoke **those kind of cigarettes**?
>
> This structure is often felt to be incorrect, and is usually avoided
>   in a formal style. This can be done by using singular noun (see
>   above), by using plural *sorts/kinds/types*, or by using structure
>   *...of this/that sort/kind/type*:
>
> > **This sort of car** is ... 
> >     **These kinds of car(s)** are ... 
> >     **Cars of that type** are ...
>
> <sub>**Source -** Practical English Usage by Michael Swan</sub>

Comment: I'm currently reading your post! :) . . . But could you add the page numbers/section-identifiers? And maybe the author and date to that grammar source "A Comprehensive Grammar of English Language"? And maybe double check the spellings in the excerpts? (e.g. *"But in informal context, the **followings** are also acceptable"*) . . . am reading . . . :)

Comment: *"These/Those sort/kind/type of parties are dangerous."* <== That's a GOOD example! But I'd like to know the exact source of where it is coming from.

Comment: @F.E Oh that is my sentence :-) I remember it's there in section 10.43. I wrote it this way because the way the book wrote it, it's not possible to write it that way here. My book is rather current, it's 2007 edition :-)

Comment: But what book and author is it? And in general, you need to have the exact text in the excerpt (no paraphrase); the paraphrase could be added, but outside the excerpt.

Comment: @F.E oh sorry I will edit it, but plz not before tomorrow :-) on my phn now. It's the same author Quirk and Leech and others.

Comment: @F.E Ahh I see... It should be **following** without that **s**.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait till tomorrow when you've had a chance to edit your post. :) . . . If you could, it would be nice, and highly informative, if you would insert some excerpts from the 2002 *MWCDEU* -- you might find their info to be enlightening. :)

Comment: Oh, +1 for inserting excerpts from grammar and usage sources. :)

Comment: @F.E I will edit it surely and will add authors' name. Don't worry :-) it's past midnight here, so I have to go to sleep real quick :-) in one of comments I saw you asked OP to check mw usage book, but unfortunately that 2002 edition I don't have. I have an old edition of that book, that I already checked.

Comment: In my opinion, the older 1989/94 *MWDEU* isn't as good (it is a different book), for it seems to have some old-fashion prescriptivist stuff in it. But maybe you could check that one out too, and if necessary, use excerpts from that one. Aside: the 2002 CGEL does have a little bit on this topic too, though it is a very, very little bit.

Comment: @F.E. I have updated it. Please have a look, the last sentence I quoted from that book is completely from different portion than the first portion I quoted. So to maintain uniformity of this answer I added my own sentence in between(not under quotation). I also provided a screenshot of the entry 10.43 (Not complete though, but relevant). Provided page no. and authors. My book's edition is 2010 (sorry for previous wrong info), but both in 1985 edition and this edition the page number from where I quoted is the same.

Comment: @F.E. What is the meaning of **pause filler**? (in *Some
uses such as *these type of things* show it as a routine **pause filler***)

Comment: w.r.t. "pause filler", that book that used that term might also define what they mean by it. Tentatively, to me, it seems that they might have been intentionally stretching the usual meanings of that term to indicate that the speaker might have misspoken or changed their mind as to what they wanted to say. (But in any case, their opining done there seems dubious to me.)

Comment: Your answer post currently has some excerpts in it, but each excerpt by itself might lead a person astray--they remind me of the story ["The blind men describing an elephant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). 
I'd strongly suggest you read the info that's in the *Merriam-Webster's Concise Dictionary of English Usage* (MWCDEU) on entry "kind" pages 452-4. It is a usage dictionary, and it spends around 1,500 words discussing this specific issue. Their info will help you to understand how to evaluate the excerpts that you currently have in your answer post.

Comment: *MWCDEU*, page 453: ==> "To sum up: we can find both *kind* and *sort* in the singular preceded by a singular and followed by a singular; in the singular preceded by a singular and followed by a plural; and in the singular preceded by a plural and followed by a plural. And *kinds* and *sorts* are followed both by singulars and plurals. All these permutations have been in use since the 18th century or earlier, and they are still in use: …" <== and they provide evidence to support their argumentation. You need to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The former example, "two types of user are identified", is correct. You should say "This type of user...", or "This color car...", or "This species of tree...", not "This type of users..." or "This color cars...", or "This species of trees." So then, the plural of "type of user" is "types of user".

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly futile to try to decide on logical or patterning grounds between these two variants (as regards their acceptability).

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=type+of+thing%2Ctype+of+things%2Ctypes+of+thing%2Ctypes+of+things&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0) for *type of thing* / *type of things* / *types of thing* / *types of things* show that there is a marked preference for the matched pairings (type + thing and types + things); the mismatched pairs are relatively quite rare.

With [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=type+of+user%2Ctype+of+users%2Ctypes+of+user%2Ctypes+of+users&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20user%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctype%20of%20users%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20user%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20users%3B%2Cc0) for *type of user* / *type of users* / *types of user* / *types of users*, the matched pairings are again more popular; **however**, in these examples, the mismatched *types of user* has a significant following.

I'd say that this shows the idiosyncrasy of choice with these constructions (and the subjectivity displayed by people claiming a broad-brush 'this way is right'). Though as KeithS implies in a previous answer, there may well be the connotation of subsets with 'types of users' etc, avoided with the choice of 'types of user'.

Comment: Could you not provide us with some info from vetted grammar sources?

Comment: Both ACGEL and CGEL point out the anomalous usage _These / those kind / type / sort of dogs are dangerous_ (ACGEL labelling this 'informal'). Since this is the least common of the four variants according to Ngram data, the 'kinds of dog' usage is surely at least as acceptable. (The grammars concentrate on the agreements with determiner and verb, giving examples including eg type of dog / types of dogs. They don't go into the acceptability or otherwise of 'types of dog'.)

Comment: [This page](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22types%20of%20dog%22%20%22types%20of%20dogs%22) and [this page {both Google}](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22types+of+dog%22+%22types+of+dogs%22&start=10) show both "types of dogs" and "types of dog" happily being used by bodies you'd think reasonably literate.

Comment: Perhaps you could insert excerpts from those grammar sources (and their page numbers) into your answer post, where their info is relevant to the issue at hand (e.g. *"These kind of dogs are dangerous*" is considered acceptable for informal style by H&P CGEL). I'm interested in seeing at least the page numbers (or section numbers) for the related info in the reference grammars, especially for the 1985 Quirk et al. since it's very hard to find stuff in there via the index.

Comment: Look up 'type/s of' in the index / lexical index. They're not strictly relevant to OP's actual question.

Comment: Those pages in the 1985 Quirk et al. is covering the same little tidbit as is done in the 2002 CGEL. Though that tidbit isn't directly related to the OP's issue, it does have the good point of showing that the acceptable usage is more than what AmE prescriptive rules have opined. An answer post would be stronger having that tidbit (imo). The OP's topic has been discussed in some decent sources (such as in *MWCDEU*). The problem of merely having some google and ngram is that that is basically all that it is, and there are already many answer posts of dubious quality that have only them.

Answer (score -2):

If someone were to say or write “There are two types of user”, I would paraphrase it as:

> **There is user A** and [there is] **user B**

However, if faced with the following construction:

> There are two types of **person**
>   or
>   There two types of **people**

I would naturally opt for the second version. The phrase: *There are two* has a plural verb; the noun phrase, *type of person* is singular, and normally the noun agrees with the verb.  In the OP's example, *user*, which is a regular noun,  can be made plural by adding the suffix -s.

> Two types of users **are** identified.

In other words, the singular *“I can identify one type of user”*, is made plural like so: *“I can identify **two types** of **users**”

Comment: The subject of the plural verb is *types.*  The other noun, *user/users/person/people,* is the object of the preposition *of.*  It is not necessary for the object of the preposition to agree with the verb.  (Also, *thus* is already an adverb.  It does not take *ly.*)

Comment: @phoog my understanding is that "type of user" is the noun phrase. As for "thus" and "thusly" [they're the same](http://grammarist.com/usage/thusly/) I am free to choose which one I prefer.

Comment: Sure, it is a noun phrase.  Its number is therefore determined by its head: *type* or *types.* That doesn't mean its plural can't be "types of user."  Consider "attorneys in fact," "cups of coffee," "cities under siege," etc.  As for thusly, have you read what the AHD usage panel has to say? https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=T5215200

Comment: @phoog Would you write "There are two types of person"?

Comment: In many contexts, I would.  I certainly find none of the instances of "types of person" found using Google to sound incorrect, or even awkward, though it is clear that "types of people" is more popular.