# "Types of cars" or "Types of car"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Would you say 
"The different types of cars" 
or 
"The different types of car"?

In reality my doubt is about types of event/events but can be more confusing to explain what I mean.

I have many events of the different types.

Comment: I would you say "The different events", or "The different types of event", or "The different kinds of event".

Comment: @WeatherVane both types and kinds would be right, but I need to use one of them because they define some common characteristics of the groups of events.

Answer (score 0):

The [types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing) post discusses which is more grammatical but I think this is a different question.

"Types of car" would describe different forms of the concept of "car".

> hybrid, sub-compact and flying are all types of car

While types of cars describes members of the set of cars.

> Fords, Toyotas, Volvos are all types of cars

.