# Different types of shoppers or shopper?

Tags: grammar

"How different types of shopper respond to colors?"

Could any native speaker tell me why above sentence is correct?  I think it should be "How different types of shopper**s** respond to colors?"

I have read already read [Types of things vs. types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing)
but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Types of things vs. types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing)

Comment: This question certainly is a duplicate of that question, regardless of its answers. But many of the answers there would also be given here. (As a native speaker, my personal preference is the singular *shopper*. But other native speakers will no doubt prefer the plural. You can avoid the issue by dropping *types of* altogether—which results in a clear plural *shoppers*.)

Comment: I am preparing myself for IELTS exam. That is why I'm asking this question because I head in audio "How different types of shopper respond to colors" but I don't really know why it is correct @JasonBassford

Comment: Look here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/141292/14666

Answer (score 1):

A singular, countable noun may be used [*generically*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/generic-nouns/), that is, representing an entire class rather than a single specific.

> You might say that [*the written text*](https://books.google.de/books?id=vWKMAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT126&dq=%22the+written+text+is%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP1N6RnaveAhXQYVAKHRlcCUQ4ChDoAQgkMAA) is one partner in a further dialogue, a dialogue between the reader and the text. This also would help to explain why Plato's dialogues are so literary. — Peter Adamson, *Classical Philosophy: A history of philosophy without any gaps*, vol.1,  2014.

This dialogue occurs when *any* reader encounters *any* text: both of these singular nouns are used generically.

> However, ever since Koch and Oesterreicher's (1985) seminal work, [*spoken discourse and written texts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=VzXJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&dq=%22written+texts+are%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNrfHrnaveAhUSZVAKHZa-BdAQ6AEIUTAI) are no longer seen as a dichotomy. *Developments in English*, 2014, 162.

Here, *spoken discourse* (generic) is opposed to (all) *written texts* in the plural: basically a stylistic choice. Strict parallel structure, however, could just as easily have suggested keeping both as generic singulars: “spoken discourse and the written text.”

In the same way, in the collocation *different types of x*, a writer may choose to use a generic singular or a universal plural:

> In history, pupils produce many [*different types of text*](https://books.google.de/books?id=lRwSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&dq=%22different+types+of%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRxObimKveAhVOZlAKHZzWCaE4WhDoAQgzMAM). They need to understand how texts are structured in order to produce historical writing that meets the need of different types of historical enquiry.  — Caroline Coffin, *Historical Discourse: The Language of Time, Cause and Evaluation*, 2009.
>
> As classroom teachers in the primary grades, our role is crucial in both setting the course for comprehension instruction and ensuring that children have opportunities to think literally, inferentially, and critically about many [*different types of text*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tc18BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=%22different+types+of+text%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx2aPhmaveAhWJZlAKHc9_BGgQ6AEITTAI), and to express that thinking through verbal and written formats. — Katherine A. Dougherty Stahl, Georgia Earnest Garcia, *Developing Reading Comprehension*, 2015.
>
> Scripture includes many [*different types of texts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=7GapAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&dq=%22different+types+of+texts%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi06fSIpqveAhWPJlAKHeMQDMI4PBDoAQhPMAg) – with genres as far apart as poetry, proverbs, hymns of praise and lament, and ethical exhortations. — Mary Grey, *The Resurrection of Peace*, 2012.
>
> Thanks also to the copyeditor for dealing with dozens of [*different types of texts*](https://books.google.de/books?id=MRB5AAAAQBAJ&pg=PR11&dq=%22different+types+of+texts%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqq7Scm6veAhUQUlAKHfMjBD84MhDoAQg2MAM) and citation systems from dozens of different authors and for dealing with the wonderful variety of names and spellings on display in the ancient geographers and ethnographers.  — Rebecca F. Kennedy, C. Sydnor Roy, Max L. Goldman, *Race and Ethnicity in the Classical World*, 2013.

In the last example, the plural *texts* prohibits the reader from parsing the object of the preposition *of*  as *text and citation systems*, and thus is a much better stylistic choice. Otherwise, there is really no hard and fast rule dictating which a writer should choose.