# Singular vs plural when listing multiple items

Tags: grammaticality

> Mutation of the human genome results in three classes of genomic
> variant: single nucleotide; short insertions or deletions; and large
> structural variants (SVs).

Is this case, should genomic variant be singular or plural? More importantly, why is it so?

Comment: That's kind of tricky...it might require a user with specific knowledge to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing

Comment: Hi Xanne. Thank you, this is a duplicate of that question.