# This type of + plural ( reason)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary, tenses, sentence

As we all agree on, types when plural, always comes after "of" a plural noun.. Like types of cars : meaning different classes of cars. My question here is : when I want to address one type of the "types" of cars, why should make "car" not cars to be this type of car, not cars?? Another example : we have different types of students, but this type of students is the hardest to deal with?  As here I address one type of "different types " as the prepositional phrase "of students"works as an adjective for types or"type"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types of things vs. types of thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing)

Comment: type of car is not a brand. An SUV is a type of car. A Toyota is a brand or make of car. In standard grammar: These types of students and This type of student don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a tendency: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+car%2Ctypes+of+cars&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20cars%3B%2Cc0), [robe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+robe%2Ctypes+of+robes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20robe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20robes%3B%2Cc0), [house](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+house%2Ctypes+of+houses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20houses%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20houses%3B%2Cc0), [student](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=types+of+student%2Ctypes+of+students&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20students%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctypes%20of%20students%3B%2Cc0). It cannot be said that the use of the singular is wrong, this being so because too large a number of people use it and because there is nothing that can be said to be illogical in this practice.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give Google NGrams more data to work with, I use *thing(s)* at the ends of phrases, rather than *car(s)* or *student(s)*. [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+type+of+things%2Cthese+types+of+thing%2Cthese+types+of+things%2Cthese+type+of+things&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20type%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20types%20of%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20types%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20type%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0) shows that the following four types of plural are used in this order of frequency (most frequent at the top):

- these types of things
- these type of things
- this type of things
- these types of thing

I got the same order when using [*kind* instead of *type*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+kind+of+things%2Cthese+kinds+of+thing%2Cthese+kinds+of+things%2Cthese+kind+of+things&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20kind%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20kinds%20of%20thing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20kinds%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20kind%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0); the order is

- these kinds of things
- these kind of things
- this kind of things
- these kinds of thing

In both cases, the phrase with the adjective and both nouns all plural is the most prevalent usage by far.